# How to fetch data from NSManaged object context

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchLLObjects = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchLLObjects setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

[fetchLLObjects setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID



NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *allObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchLLObjects error:&error];
```

Here array is showing nil. But in database I could see that there are data. I don't know what might be the reason.

Comment: Comment out setIncludesPropertyValues:NO. Is the result still nil?

Comment: yes I'm still getting the nil value.

Comment: is the error object nil after fetch request?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your predicate in the fetchrequest

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"managedObjectID == %@", managedObjectID]]                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: I'm very new to this ios.Please tell me how to get managedObjectID

Comment: Setting a predicate is optional and isn't the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Set following 2 properties and you are done.

```
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];

//Take properties dictionary
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"song_type"]]];
NSArray * result = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: for NSDictionary *entityProperties is also showing nil.

Answer (score 0):

You said: "But in database I could see that there are data."

I'm skeptical of that statement. I suspect that no `CustomerOrder` objects exist in the Core Data store. The only way to "see" the data inside the store is to turn off journaling mode and use 3rd party software to peak inside the .sqlite file.

Despite what others have said, your fetch request is fine.  So double check your code where you insert objects into the store and save to the context.